# Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysqli, runtime-error

I am getting this error from the following code:

```
function updateRank($master_list, $event_id)
{
    $cnt_ml =  count($master_list);
    echo "count master list = $cnt_ml<br>";

    $b=1;

    for ($k=0; $k<$cnt_ml; $k++)
    {
        echo "master list element 1 - ".$master_list[1]."<br>";
        $foo = $master_list[$k];

        // Update each team in event_team table             
        $update = "UPDATE event_team 
                  SET pool_rank = $b 
                  WHERE event_id = $event_id
                  AND team_id = $foo";

        mysqli_query($conn, $update);// or die ('Could not run insert in event_team table');



        echo "|".$update."|<br>";   // Leave this line for debugging the sql query.
        $b++;
    }   
}
```

Specifically "$foo" is throwing the error. The "master_list" array is being passed correctly. When running the code, $cnt_ml returns "5" (which is absolutely correct). The line with:

```
echo "master list element 1 - ".$master_list[1]."<br>";
```

Returns "54" (which is correct).

Since the script is successfully able to read the array elements and post them, why is the script throwing the error when I include it in the UPDATE? It is able to see the array data but choking when trying to use the data in the UPDATE.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what error is it throwing?

Comment: ^^^ the best comment of the year

Comment: Could you show us a var_dump of your array?

Comment: The error message is the title of the post. Sorry. I should have made that clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable $conn is not declared. Or it's declared globally and you forgot to add

```
global $conn;
```

in updateRank function

Comment: That was it. "$conn" was not declared globally. That solved my problem. MANY THANKS!!!!